# AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate Error When Capturing Image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation, avcapturephotosettings

I seem to get this error message randomly after a few cycles of capture:

> Error finishing photo: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain
>   Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-16802),
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x281f20f30 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain
>   Code=-16802 "(null)"}}

Error occurs in:

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {}
```

---

Notes:

- This Error never comes up on the first capture.
- The image format is also a processed format: HEIF
- iOS 13

Comment: Might this be related? https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/101588

Comment: -12686 indicates that there was a buffer allocation failure near the beginning of the camera pipeline.
-16802 is similarly an indication of still image failure at the driver layer.

Comment: Those seem to be very helpful from that thread.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, the culprit was stabilization. I was setting
    settings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = true
while capturing the image. Stabilization is a heavy process which on main thread which hinders the buffer allocation. Moved it to where camera was getting initialized, resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Interesting! So what exactly are you doing at the time of camera initialization?

Comment: setting up input, outputs and camera session, configuring settings and adding observers

Comment: I meant, how do you initiate AVCapturePhotoSettings just at the time of camera initialization, since it has to be done per capture?